# Parsing output of a telnet/ssh session

Tags: python, parsing, ssh, telnet

I am going to write a script to parse a lot of log files, these files are on remote servers, so my script will have to telnet/ssh to these remote servers in order to issue some commands/CLI to get the data. Its going to be a lot of data, so i would like to know from your experience what is the best option to do this ? Is it to download the commands output to local files and then do the parsing ? or do it in-line? What makes one option better than other? Other than occupying disk space.

Thanks,
Kim

Comment: **It depends**. I have huge disk space. But low bandwidth. I usually write script that executes on remote server over ssh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may not code the data retrieving procedure inside your parser program, keeping your free to use unix tools like cat to conCATenate, zcat to gunzip while concatenating, ssh to touch remote servers, even grep, awk etc... parsing local files, like test files, etc...

```
ssh example.com cat file | ./parse.py -
```

Advantages:

- You do not hard code the "way" data is downloaded.
- You do not store the file locally.
- You can change your mind without changing the code
- ArgumentParser can open stdin when giving "-" as a file name.
- You can parse gzipped log: ssh example.com zcat file.gz | ./parse.py -
- Or concatenate multiple logs: ssh example.com zcat logfile-2014-06-*.gz | ./parse.py -
- Free you some bandwidth by filtering before transmitting: ssh example.com zgrep -v useless logfile-2014-06-*.gz | ./parse.py -
- And so on...